# Is there a way could deploy Django project on namecheap in ASGI mode?

Tags: django, web-deployment, uvicorn, namecheap, asgi

I'm trying to deploy my Django on Namecheap, the server should work but I got the following message traceback:

> ```
> [ERROR] [UID:12123][2655752] wsgiAppHandler pApp->start_response() return NULL.
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/alshigpf/website/passenger_wsgi.py", line 41, in __call__
>     return self.app(environ, start_response)
> TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'send'
> [ERROR] [UID:12123][2655752] wsgiAppHandler pApp->start_response() return NULL.
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/alshigpf/website/passenger_wsgi.py", line 41, in __call__
>     return self.app(environ, start_response)
> TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'send'
> ```

This is what my passenger_wsgi.py file looks like:

```
import os
import sys
import django

sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'website.settings.development'
django.setup()

SCRIPT_NAME = os.getcwd()
print("Script name: ", SCRIPT_NAME)


class PassengerPathInfoFix(object):
    """
        Sets PATH_INFO from REQUEST_URI because Passenger doesn't provide it.
    """
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
        print("Start Init")
        print("App is: ", self.app)
        print("End Init")

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        from urllib.parse import unquote
        print("Start Calling")
        environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = SCRIPT_NAME
        request_uri = unquote(environ['REQUEST_URI'])
        script_name = unquote(environ.get('SCRIPT_NAME', ''))
        offset = request_uri.startswith(script_name) and len(environ['SCRIPT_NAME']) or 0
        environ['PATH_INFO'] = request_uri[offset:].split('?', 1)[0]
        return self.app(environ, start_response)

# Get ASGI application 
from website.routing import application
print("Before calling application")

application = PassengerPathInfoFix(application)
```

when I googled I glanced that there's something called "Uvicorn" which is an updated version of Gunicorn to handle ASGI mode.

when I did an advanced search on google to see if namecheap.com talk about using uvicorn I didn't find anything related to this problem.

so, my question is: how can I ignore this issue by still using ASGI mode instead of WSGI?